# How to use in Google Sheets setValue only for range of filtered rows (getRange for not hidden cells)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, range

I want to know, how to use setValue, if there are filtered rows, so that only the shown rows (C1 + one row down to last row of C) get a value.

```
x(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(C2, lastRow).setValue('x');
}
```

## Update

It works, but very slowly. I have tested the following code and it works fast. It must start in the second shown row. The following solution works both with and without filter. What is not yet running is the second row (C2). The copied value is always inserted there. In addition I would like to do without an auxiliary cell for copying if possible. Is it possible to copy setValue for the copypaste function (getValue)?

```
function x() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:'+'C'+lastRow).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

The goal is to put an x in the currently visible (not the hidden or non-visible filtered) cells of column C. For this I just need to know how to specify the second visible cell as getRange value (with offset for example), because the rest (end cell: lastRow) is working (correct selection and input, only C2, everytime, if i'm using this script, there is in C2 a x):

```
spreadsheet.getRange('C2:'+'C'+lastRow).activate();
```

The first row is fixed. How to use the first visibile not fixed row (second row) for getRange? If the last row is hidden and the script is used, no x is set there, probably because of 'C'+lastRow. This works. Only C2 is affected.

## Here is the solution

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

function x() {
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  for(var row = 2; s.isRowHiddenByFilter(row); ++row);
  var range = s.getRange('C'+row+':C'+lastRow);
  s.getRange('F1').copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Understanding

- You want to put the value using `setValue` to the showing rows of the filtered column (column "C").
- The filter is the basic filter.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, you can retrieve the row numbers of the shown and hidden rows by the filter using `isRowHiddenByFilter`.

  - When `isRowHiddenByFilter` is `true`, the row is hiding.
  - When `isRowHiddenByFilter` is `false`, the row is showing.
- The range list is created from the retrieved row numbers and is used for `setValue`.

#### Modified script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var ranges = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
  if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1)) {
    ranges.push("C" + (i + 1));
  }
}
sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue('x');
```

- When you run the script, the value of `x` is put to the showing rows of the column "C".
- If `if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1)) {` is modified to `if (sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1)) {`, the value of `x` is put to the hidden rows.

#### References:

- [isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#isRowHiddenByFilter(Integer))
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))

Comment: I found out that getDataRange is faster than getRange. How can it be integrated into the function? Maybe it is as fast as manual insertion.

Comment: @user8652270 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. I understand about your question as `You want to put the value using setValue to the showing rows of the filtered column (column "C").`. Was my understanding not correct? If my understanding is not correct, can I ask you about your issue? I would like to think of your issue by correctly understanding of your issue. So if you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Above I've sent some informations of a newer, faster solution (look for Update please).

Comment: @user8652270 Thank you for replying. At first, can I ask you whether my understanding for your question is correct? And I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I saw your updated question. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about what you want to do. Can I ask you about your goal?

Comment: @user8652270 If you want to set the value of `x` from the row 2, please modify `for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {` to `for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {` in the script of my answer. But unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal. So if this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: It's very slowly. Cause of that I want to use `CopyPasteType`. How to only select the second and last shown cell of column c to use this (see above), for example with c1 plus offset 1 down? For CopyPasteType it would be optimal if not the auxiliary cell (for example C1) is used for copy to paste, but getValue or something else if possible or useful.

Comment: @user8652270 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `How to only select the second and last shown cell of column c to use this (see above), for example with c1 plus offset 1 down?`, you want to select the row 1 and the last row at the column "C". Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is not correct, can you provide a sample input and output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand about your goal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210286/discussion-between-user8652270-and-tanaike).