# How can the SpreadsheetApp calls be reduced to get all non-hidden rows for a rangelist 10 to 100 times or more faster?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, push

How can the following code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60823521/8652270) be converted to work similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61306738/8652270 with isRowHiddenByFilter and isRowHiddenByUser? For example, 100 rows could be checked in 1 second instead of 30 if all values are cached once before.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var ranges = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
  if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1)) {
    ranges.push("C" + (i + 1));
  }
}
sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue('x');
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array, where the visible values are mapped to "x"  and leave the hidden values as is.
- Use the mapped array to  directly `setValues` on the `range`.

```
const getVisibleValuesMarkedWithStr_ = (
  shtName,
  rngString,
  sheet = shtName ? SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(shtName) : null,
  range = sheet ? sheet.getRange(rngString) : null,
  stringToMark
) => {
  return range
    .getValues()
    .map((row, rowIdx) =>
      !sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(rowIdx + 1) &&
      !sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(rowIdx + 1)
        ? row.fill(stringToMark)
        : row
    );
};

function x() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const range = sheet.getRange(`C1:C${lastRow}`);
  range.setValues(getVisibleValuesMarkedWithStr_(null, null, sheet, range, 'x'));
}
```

Comment: A test only with `isRowHiddenByFilter` resulted, when the rows 1 and 200 to 203 were displayed, with the new code 52 seconds, with the old 38 and with manual preselection (`s.getRange(cell).copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);`) less than 1 second. I thought the Spreadsheet service is very fast with only one call, or am I wrong?

Comment: @user8652270 Add in a few more hidden rows and see? Say every alternate row 1,3,7... 100 in 100 rows and see. In any case, I expect copy-paste to be fast. My answer should be faster than rangelist method however.

Comment: I don't know why, but if this code is used (see under solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60823352/8652270)), an `x` is only set in the non-hidden cells. This applies only to `isRowHiddenByFilter`. A manual preselection is not necessary (misunderstanding).

Comment: @user8652270 Is there a question? Did you test performance with hiding multiple alternate rows?

Comment: Yes, some tests have already been done. I like the idea, but it needs speed. The code under the above link uses a for loop. If it is possible to calculate the first and last non-hidden row using a cell formula, the time can be significantly shortened if the auxiliary cell is used with copyTo. Is there a formula for this?

Comment: @user8652270 Sounds like you  should ask a new question. I am not getting half of what you're saying.